# Is there a way to test the image on PDF files?

Tags: java, pdf, selenium-webdriver, ocr, ui-automation

In our project, we have requirement to test the PDF file data. But few of the data in PDF file is in image format, so we can not apply the same logic as we apply for text comparison on PDF. We are facing problem to verify that image text on PDF file. Is there any API from which we can recognize the OCR and extract the text from image and compare it.

Comment: I would advice that you separate the issue, first merely extract the bitmap images (should be possible using any general purpose PDF library unless advanced colorspaces are used) and then apply OCR to the images (there are some libraries for that task, too).

Answer (score 1):

To work with images you can try -

1. Java for image comparison but it will become very difficult to handle the codes with in progress of the project.
2. I generally use sikuli for the image reorganization purpose and it works very well plz download sikuli form [here](http://www.sikulix.com/) and for a working example with sikuli plz have a look at [here](http://doc.sikuli.org/faq/030-java-dev.html).

Answer (score 1):

Can you preprocess the PDF Files? If so, please try pdf2pdfocr (https://github.com/LeoFCardoso/pdf2pdfocr).

Disclaimer: I'm pdf2pdfocr developer.